# WinJS.UI.ListLayout make contenteditable on one item but have itemsReorderable

Tags: javascript, winjs

How to make content of one column in item in WinJS.UI.ListLayout editable `contenteditable="true"`, but remaining list columns remain active to other operations of ListLayout such as `itemsReorderable="true"`?

e.g. column:

`<div class="person" data-win-bind="innerText: person" contenteditable="true"></div>`

list view config:

`data-win-options="{
layout:{type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout },
itemsReorderable: true,
...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found answer:
class `win-interactive` has to be used inside that element or in any of it's parents.

`<div class="person win-interactive" data-win-bind="innerText: person" contenteditable="true"></div>`

This disable ListView behavior for an item and make possible adding interactive elements to an item template.

Based on this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700705.aspx